# How to put a StreamBuilder back into ConnectionState.waiting

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `StreamBuilder` with RxDart and a `BehaviorSubject`. The `StreamBuilder` listens to the `Observable` from the `BehaviorSubject` and I have run into a situation where I would like to put the `StreamBuilder` back into `ConnectionState.waiting`.

Using the `BehaviorSubject` or its `Observable`, how can I go about putting the `StreamBuilder` back into `ConnectionState.waiting`?

Comment: i dont think it is possible at all

Comment: btw what do you need it for?

Comment: I would like to be able to put it back in a waiting state until the next item is sent. But only for that item. Then it stays in the active state after that. I would like that so I can show a loading indicator while I'm saving an item in my SQLLite db.

Comment: hmmm, maybe you could extend `StreamBuilder` and override one of `after*` methods.... just wild guess

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that may be an option.